# Meteor and Node virtual host

Tags: node.js, meteor, vhosts

I have the need to run 2 servers, one in Node.js and one with Meteor, let's say on my_server.com

- The Node server listens on   `my_server.com:8080`,
- The Meteor server listens on `my_server.com:3000`

I'd like to open just the port :80, and then redirect the user with vhost of Node according to the subdomain, so

- `node.my_server.com:80`  should go to `my_server.com:8080`
- `meteor.my_server.com:80`  should go to `my_server.com:3000`

and I want to open just one port. Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's totally possible, you should use nginx of apache for that.

Here is example nginx config:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           node.my_server.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/node.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/node.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1: 8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

And similar one for meteor

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           meteor.my_server.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/meteor.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/meteor.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1: 3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```